# how to grep a string from file in skill file(.il)

Tags: cadence, cadence-virtuoso

```
sumfile = simplifyFilename("getWorkingDir/perc.sum")
sumpath = strcat("grep -r "RUN COMPLETED" " sumfile " > out.txt")
print(sumpath)
system(sumpath)
```

am getting error as
*Error* lineread/read: syntax error encountered in input

Answer (score 1):

You should escape quote marks. See below

```
strcat("grep -r \"RUN COMPLETED\" " sumfile " > out.txt")
```